# Найти количество равных и различных элементов в массиве

Tags: c++

Искал в интернете множество вариантов, но все они работают криво, попробовал так на вывод явно не корректный, то есть кол-во равных элементов (кол-во повторяющихся) и кол-во различных (уникальных) вроде достаточно найти один вариант и вычесть из размера массива чтобы получить второй

[image: Пример неправильной работы]

код на repl https://repl.it/@andreykas/StarkFakeDeclarations

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class dynamic_array {
    int* data;
    int size;
    int flag;
public:
    dynamic_array(int array_size)
    {
        size=array_size;
        data=new int[size];
    }
    void rand_array(int from, int to) {
        srand(time(0));
        int from_=from;
        int to_=to;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = rand() %to_ +from_;
        }
    }
    void input_array() {
        cout <<"\nVvedite razmer massive kol=\b";
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            std::cout<<"Vvedite mas["<<(i+1)<<"]    \b\b\b";
            cin>>data[i]; 
        }

    }

    void quick_sort(int a, int b) {
        int left_index = a, right_index = b;
        int head_element = data[rand() %b +0];
            while (left_index <= right_index) {
                while (data[left_index] < head_element)
                    left_index++;
                while (data[right_index] > head_element)
                    right_index--;
                if (left_index <= right_index) {
                    if (data[left_index] != data[right_index]) {//ïðîâåðêà íà îäèíàêîâûå ýëåìåíòû ñ ðàçíûìè èíäåêñàìè
                        swap(data[left_index], data[right_index]);
                        flag++;
                        //display_quick_sort();
                    }
                    left_index++;
                    right_index--;
                }
            }
        //if (a < right_index)
        if (right_index-a > 1)
            quick_sort(a, right_index);
        else if ((a < right_index) && (data[a] > data[right_index])) {
            swap(data[a], data[right_index]);
            flag++;
            //display_quick_sort();
        }
        //if (b > left_index)
        if (b - left_index > 1)
            quick_sort(left_index, b);
        else if ((b > left_index) && (data[b] < data[left_index])){ 
            swap(data[b], data[left_index]);
            flag++;
            //display_quick_sort();
        }
    }

    int equal_and_unequal_count(int *unequal_count) {
        int equal_count = 0;
        int unequal_flag = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<size; j++) {
                if (data[i]==data[j]) equal_count++;
            }   
        }

        *unequal_count=size-equal_count;
        return equal_count;
    }

    void display_array() {
        cout <<"Massive:" <<"\n";
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            cout <<data[i]<<"  ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    ~dynamic_array()
    {
        delete[] data;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int N, unequal_count;
    cout << "Enter amount of numbers in massive: ";
    cin >> N;

    dynamic_array my_array(N);
    my_array.rand_array(0, 10);
    //my_array.input_array();
    my_array.display_array();
    my_array.quick_sort(0, N-1);
    my_array.display_array();

    cout << "amount of equal is: " << my_array.equal_and_unequal_count(&unequal_count) << endl;

    cout << "amount of UNequal is: " << unequal_count;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А `std::set` нельзя использовать ? Вы всё равно сортировку делаете, те же O(NlogN) получатся

Comment: пробовал но не разобрался как это дело к классу подрубить

Comment: К какому классу ?

Comment: А, всё. Вы же знаете про std::vector, std::sort, std::set, std::map и прочее и пишите класс для обучения, да? Тогда не важно, вручную даже полезнее, наверное.

Comment: да для обучения

Comment: непонятно что называется равным элементов а что не равным ??? , по примеру из скрина я вижу 3 уникальных (0, 1, 5) и 3 повторяющихся элемента (2, 4, 8), откуда ответ 5, 5 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Массив же сортирован, для него количества можно найти примерно так (если я правильно понимаю, что должно быть в equal_count)

```
void equal_and_unequal_count() {
    int data[10] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int size = 10;
    int equal_count = 0;
    int uneq_count = 0;
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        if (i == size || data[i] != data[i - 1]) {
            if (i - 1 == start)
                uneq_count++;
            else
                equal_count += (i - start);
            start = i;
        }
    cout << equal_count << " " << uneq_count;
}
```

Comment: вывод такой при данных числах
1  1  2  3  3  3  4  5  6  7
amount of equal is: 45
amount of UNequal is: 4197040

Comment: а должен быть что то вроде 5 equal и 5 unequal

Comment: start не обновлялся

Comment: благодарю, подправил для своего варианта https://pastebin.com/AtaumYev

Answer (score 0):

Есть много способов

1) Самый очевидный - перебор за **O(N^2)**

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    bool fl = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (i != j && a[i] == a[j]) {
          fl = false;
          break;
        }
    if (fl) k++;
}
cout << "equal: " << k << "\nunequal: " << n - k;
```

2) Оптимизация с сортировкой за **O(N*log(N))**

```
int k = 0;
sort(a, a + n);
for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    if (a[i] != a[i-1] && a[i] != a[i+1]) k++;
if (n == 1) k = 1;
if (a[0] != a[1] && n > 1) k++;
if (a[n-1] != a[n-2] && n > 1) k++;
cout << "equal: " << k << "\nunequal: " << n - k;
```

3) Компактно и понятно через `map` за **O(N*log(N))**, хотя медленнее второго варианта *(константа больше)*

```
int k = 0;
map<int, int> list;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) list[a[i]]++;
for (auto i : list) if (i.second == 1) k++;
cout << "equal: " << k << "\nunequal: " << n - k;
```

ПС для новичков

Один из вариантов выше вставлять сюда

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>  //надо в 3-м способе

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "n = ";
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];

    //--- сюда вставлять код одного из вариантов выше ---
}
```

Comment: Для тестового примера (скрин в вопросе) ответом должно быть
`equal: 3
unequal: 7`

Comment: Откуда unequal 7 ? равных тоесть повторяющихся 3 (это 2, 4, 8) а неравных (уникальных) тоже 3 (это 0, 1, 5)

Comment: Не стоит полностью дублировать ответ. Если вы считаете, что вопрос - повтор уже существующего - просто оставьте на нем тревогу соответствующего типа

Comment: @ampawd в данном случае каждый повторяющийся элемент считается столько раз, сколько он встречается в исходной последовательности (т.е. три раза 2, два раза 4, два раза 8). Автор вопроса сам написал, что второй ответ получается вычитанием из размера первого ответа. Если критично - могу решить и для вашей интерпретации (напишите если надо). И от этого временная сложность алгоритмом (всех трёх) не измениться

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, буду знать